# Curve is geometrically irreducible over some extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve over a field $k$, i.e., an separated integral scheme of finite type over $k$, of dimension 1.

> Is it true that then there is a field extension $k' / k$ such that the map $C \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ factors through $\mathrm{Spec}(k')$ and such that $C  \to \mathrm{Spec}(k')$ is geometrically irreducible? If so, can we assume that $k' / k$ is finite?

For instance,
if $k = \mathbb{F}_q$,
then the curve $C = \mathbb{P}^1_{ \mathbb{F}_{q^2} }$ seen over $k$ is not geometrically integral, but $C$ is geometrically integral as a curve over $k' = \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

Comment: If $X$ is integral, normal and of finite type over $k$, then you may take $k'$ to be the separable closure of $k$ in the function field of $X$ (normality is required to ensure that $k'$ is inside the coordinate ring of any open affine subscheme, so that you get a morphism $X\to{\rm Spec}\,k'$). The field $k'$ is then finite over $k$ by the weak Nullstellensatz. See Qing Liu's book, Cor. 2.14, p. 91.

Comment: @DamianRössler : thank you very much, it could be written as an answer!